# Compile-time transformation of string literal types

Tags: typescript

I'm not too familiar with how TypeScript works behind the scenes yet, so I was wondering if someone could let me know if this is possible, and if not, why that is the case.

My goal is to essentially "generate" a type using a plain JavaScript function. Obviously, you cannot apply functions to types, so I started looking for some sort of construct to achieve similar results.

```
const lower = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const

/**
 * The goal is to generate a "mapping" type equivalent to { 'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C' }
 * such that, for example, Upper['a'] => 'A'
 */
type Upper = {
  [c in typeof lower[number]]: c.toUpperCase() // obviously doesn't work
}
```

I initially tried to see if TS would allow me to define a "compile-time-only function", but could not find anything; I'm assuming it is a limitation of the compiler to execute arbitrary functions.

Are there any alternatives, apart from manually writing the mapping in the above example? If not, what is preventing TS from allowing us to define compile-time transformations?

Answer (score 3):

While you can't apply normal JS functions to TS types, you can apply generic helper types, such as `Uppercase<>`:

```
const lower = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const

/**
 * The goal is to generate a "mapping" type equivalent to { 'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C' }
 * such that, for example, Upper['a'] => 'A'
 */
type Upper = {
  [c in typeof lower[number]]: Uppercase<c> // works
}
```

[image]

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiA7gUwE4wLwwNoHICGuANDLgEbGnC4C6M+EMokUAsAFAcD0AVDxzB4wAKgAtkMAOYh8cGAEtGUEFORg0+KBPwwARAFt8AByPywk3TCgBPIxOQBHAK7yAbrLWxlMAN6lCAFykAIKU5LhBuABCYdSRAMK4MAC+AkIQTsCiVqKaJABmIOjIAB74+kZwyCQAqiZoeIR0GAB8IbhpXBw2djB1duhYPgI4wApgVrbIIPnwSA1gTvpkaDQ0Qf1owAzIADzAbVxcMCBkrvIgThBw1jAAJiDIEGC4sIhFANYcyUA)

Other string literal generic helpers are listed [in the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

Comment: Ah, so they're built into the compiler. Thanks!